# How to efficiently implement this background processing chain?

Tags: c#, web-services, multiprocessing, dataflow

I am working on an audio software that uses [The EchoNest](http://the.echonest.com/) web service to identify and retrieve metadata about audio songs and I would like to have some advice on implementing a background processing chain.

*(to get the full picture, I'll show you what I did already)*

I've implemented the following chain that is mandatory before querying the service about a song's details:

[image]

Not much to say except that before being able to query song data, we need its fingerprint and a song ID returned by the *Identify* sub-process. Of all these steps, they all happen locally but the last one *(Identify)*.

**Now about the part of the system I'm seeking for advices:**

[image]

Above are the different types of queries that can be requested for a song, they are not inter-dependent as we already have the only thing needed, the song ID (diagram 1). Note that I've only put a few but there are nearly 30 of them (see [here](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4)).

**Requirements/architecture:**

1. user can drop files at any time, they are queued for identification
2. queries can run in parallel with step 1 and optionally concurrently

Ideally, the system should be:

- easily extensible when for instance, I implement a new type of query.
- easy to use, I just enqueue a query to the chain and wait for a response

**Environment:**

I am using C# with [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx), currently I've had some good success implementing diagram 1 using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13712646/361899).

### My question:

**Is there a particular/well-known pattern to tackle this problem ?**

Comment: I read your post twice, and I don't see the "problem". As soon as you used the word "chain", and mentioned asynchronous processing, I assumed you had considered a finite state machine. Does that address the issue?

Comment: Well, now that you're saying this, it seems so obvious ! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a finite state machine for the "chain," where each step in the chain is a sub-state. For example, the states may be:

- Start
- Initial processing
- Adding to collection
- Fingerprinting
- Querying
- Ready

Finite state machines are good for coordinating asynchronous operations. I would also add tracing or logging to indicate when a state transition occurs.